# my graph does does not showing correct results of fine tuning and transfer learning it is showing single line in each graph instead of two lines

Tags: python

```
acc += history_fine.history['accuracy']

val_acc += history_fine.history['val_accuracy']

loss += history_fine.history['loss']

val_loss += history_fine.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.8, 1])
plt.plot([initial_epochs-1,initial_epochs-1],
          plt.ylim(), label='Start Fine Tuning')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(loss, label='Training Loss')

plt.plot(val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.ylim([0, 1.0])
plt.plot([initial_epochs-1,initial_epochs-1],
         plt.ylim(), label='Start Fine Tuning')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, because I cannot reproduce the erroneous behaviour. For me it looks exactly how it should look like.

Comment: sir my dataset is MR images of healthy and PD patients and i am using pretrained RESNET

Comment: sir i am using MR images

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question... Could you please provide some sample of the `acc`, `val_acc`, `loss` and `val_loss` (like the first 10 values of each?).

Comment: Found 100 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 37 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 54s 14s/step - loss: 0.6015 - accuracy: 0.7000 - val_loss: 0.6964 - val_accuracy: 0.6486
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 49s 12s/step - loss: 0.5935 - accuracy: 0.7000 - val_loss: 0.5359 - val_accuracy: 0.6486
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 49s 12s/step - loss: 0.4653 - accuracy: 0.7000 - val_loss: 0.6738 - val_accuracy: 0.6486
like this sir

Comment: Rather like this: `val_accuracy = [0.6486, 0.6486, 0.6486] accuracy = [0.7000, 0.7000, 0.7000] loss = [0.6015, 0.5935, 0.4653] val_loss = [0.6964, 0.5359, 0.6738]` (this I extracted from your comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this data, I extracted from a comment of yours:

```py
initial_epochs = 2.0
val_acc = [0.6486, 0.6486, 0.6486]
acc = [0.7000, 0.7000, 0.7000]
loss = [0.6015, 0.5935, 0.4653]
val_loss = [0.6964, 0.5359, 0.6738]
```

I can plot with:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')

plt.ylim([0.4, 1]) # You had plt.ylim([0.8, 1])
plt.plot([initial_epochs-1, initial_epochs-1], plt.ylim(), label='Start Fine Tuning')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.grid() # I added a grid for both plots
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(val_loss, label='Validation Loss')

plt.ylim([0, 1.0])
plt.plot([initial_epochs-1, initial_epochs-1], plt.ylim(), label='Start Fine Tuning')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.grid() # I added a grid for both plots
plt.show()
```

I assume (based on the data I have), that the problem was due to `plt.ylim([0.8, 1])`, because `val_acc`, as well as `acc` both, were `< 0.8`, meaning the axis limits were focusing on a part of the plot where no data is.

See the following plot with `plt.ylim([0.4, 1])`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir my first graph works well but validation loss graph have still problem it is showing validation loss curve only

Comment: Have you checked the min and max values of the training loss? Might it be outside of the y-axis limits?

Comment: yes sir checked no much difference

Comment: Epoch 18/20
4/4 [==============================] - 59s 15s/step - loss: 0.5577 - accuracy: 0.8850 - val_loss: 0.7220 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 19/20
4/4 [==============================] - 59s 15s/step - loss: 0.5488 - accuracy: 0.9100 - val_loss: 0.7214 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 20/20
4/4 [==============================] - 65s 16s/step - loss: 0.5464 - accuracy: 0.9200 - val_loss: 0.7204 - val_accuracy: 0.5000

Comment: If I use this data: `loss = [0.5577, 0.5488, 0.5464] 
acc = [0.8850, 0.9100, 0.9200]
val_loss = [0.7220, 0.7214, 0.7204]
val_acc = [0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000]` I still get a nice graph, similar to the one above.

Comment: sir in my side its not working with training loss

Comment: Have u copied the code I posted above? Which `matplotlib` version are you using?

Comment: sir i have copied ur code as well but it still not works gives only single loss value